# How to show Addin settings for Outlook 365 addin

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm writing an Outlook Web Add-in using the Javascript and REST APIs.

I'm wanting to have some settings available to my GUI-less add-in.

The add-in is a spam reporter. A user clicks a button on an email, that email creates an [ARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_Reporting_Format) report and then that message is put into the trash.

The options I want to be configurable for my add-in are things like

- Delete Message afterward or Move to specific folder
- Saved ARF report in "Sent Items"
- Destination email address for ARF report (for development, this will be removed in the final version).

However I cannot find any examples of an add-in with settings, and since this is a headless add-in, I can't add a "settings" link or tab to the add-in pane (since there is no taskpane).

Anyone know how you show add-in settings for an Outlook Web Add-in?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a similar UI less action button to your manifest and use display dialog API to open up your settings page from JavaScript.

```
yourSetting = function () {
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(settingsUrl, options, callback);
}
```

Manifest with Settings button

```
<OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
    <Group id="msgMyGroup">
        <Label resid="groupLabel" />
        <!-- Your UI-less button -->
        <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgFunctionButton">
            <Label resid="functionButtonLabel" />
..
..
            <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                <FunctionName>yourFunction</FunctionName>
            </Action>
        </Control>
        <!-- Your Settings UI-less button -->
        <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgSettingsButton">
            <Label resid="settingsLabel" />
..
..
            <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                <FunctionName>yourSetting</FunctionName>
            </Action>
        </Control>
    </Group>
</OfficeTab>
```

Since you have a scenario, which needs to display some web content (Settings page) to the user, you can also create a task pane entry in the manifest and display your settings page in task pane.

Comment: hoping for a better way than this.  My options I see are
1. No settings
2. Separate button for settings - crowds the UI
3. Drop down menu with settings, but this means the main button also has to be in there, causing two clicks.

probably end up with option 1.

Comment: I am not aware of any other ways, but if you are hesitant to create a new button, then you can make it as first run experience. But this way the user won't be able to edit the settings after first run.

Comment: sadly there doesnt seem to be.  The older COM addins you could have settings elsewhere, under settings / addins / addin settings I was hoping to get something in there. Thanks anway

Comment: Currently the feature you requested is not a part of the product. However, we track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: The other option is to create a custom ribbon tab for your add-in, and call it "Spam Reporter Settings". Then you could have a settings button there and not crowd the main ribbon UI.